# Sorting Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm analyzing a Apache access log file and I want to find the hit count.
Following code does it.:

```
ips = df.groupby('IP').size()
ips.sort()
print ips[-10:]
```

But I want to find the "Referrer" (the 9th column) of the top 10 `ips`.
How can I do this?

Sample log file line:

```
112.135.128.20 - [13/May/2013:23:55:04 +0530] "GET /SVRClientWeb/ActionController HTTP/1.1" 302 2 "https://www.example.com/sample" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B329" GET /SVRClientWeb/ActionController - HTTP/1.1 www.test.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html)

You can first sort your ips and get the last 10 ips' index.

```
ips.sort()
top_ips = ips.tail(10).index
```

And then use `isin` to get the referrers you need:

```
referrers = df[df['IP'].isin(top_ips)]['Referrer']
```

Comment: The results using ips[-10:] and ips.head(10).index are different?And also it gives an error at ips.sort(ascending=False)....TypeError: sort() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ascending'

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: pandas : 0.11.0 and python 2.7

Comment: `head` is to get the first n rows.

Comment: And pandas series does have the method [sort](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.sort.html). Did I miss anything?

Comment: 141.0.9.91         477
223.224.14.55      494
141.0.10.198       502
61.245.165.57      502
103.247.48.139     518
103.247.48.184     534
111.223.157.33     880
112.135.11.195     902
124.43.4.52       1113
61.245.163.56     1643
Those were the hit counts using ips[-10:] But in the second method followings were the IPs(head(10))        110.55.4.19
     103.247.48.136
    109.165.188.150
     106.67.137.230
     108.27.225.131
     111.223.149.85
     108.232.32.132
     112.111.19.124
     110.33.230.245
     103.247.50.154

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31518/discussion-between-nilani-algiriyage-and-waitingkuo)